# Axios Get Authorization Not Working In Vue But Worked on POSTMAN (Post method on vue worked)

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, authorization

I'm Using vue for the clientside. And somehow the Authorization is not working with Get method in axios. I tried using POSTMAN and it's working like it should be. Is there any chance that I missed something?

```
getCurrentPeriode() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(TABLE_NAME,{params: {"X-API-KEY": API_KEY, command:"getCurrent"}}, {
            headers:{
                'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                resolve(response.data[0])
            }) .catch(err => {
                reject(err.response.data)
            })
    })
}
```

The token:

```
const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, 'utf8').toString('base64')
```

I get this error: ***Uncaught (in promise) {status: false, error: "Unauthorized"}***

In postman (it's worked):
[image: Postman Get]

I've tried with post method in axios and it's working. Yes I've set up CORS. Yes I've allowed Get method in my server side (coz it's working in postman)

Post method is working like normal, here's the code:

```
postNewPeriode(date) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append("dateStart", date.dateStart)
        data.append("dateEnd", date.dateEnd)
        data.append("X-API-KEY",API_KEY)
        axios.post(TABLE_NAME,data, {
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": `Basic ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                resolve(response)
            }) .catch(err => {
                reject(err.response.data)
            })
    })
},
```

Am I missing something in my axios get or I should use different approach? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Can you show other headers that you have set in Postman?

Comment: @Anatoly so the problem is the parameters order for get, BogdanC 's answer help me. btw In postman I didn't set the header in post, for the authorization I set it on the  Auth and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Axios GET, the headers should be the second argument, while for PUT and POST the body is the second and the headers the third, as you did.
Try using the headers as the second argument on GET.

This should work:

```
axios.get( TABLE_NAME, 
          { 
            headers:{'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`}, 
            params: {"X-API-KEY": API_KEY, command:"getCurrent"}
          }
         )
```

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED :D now I can sleep peacefully.